# R - Markdown : Printing the result of View() in a html report

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

Is it a way to print the result of the View() function in an html Rmarkdown report without having to take a screenshot of it and then adding it as a .png picture to the file ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use `knitr::kable()` or other functions for printing a table.

Comment: No there is not. If you are inserting screenshots of View() as images, you are missing many much better options from rmarkdown...

Comment: Ok ! Thanks @andschar ! I'll use the kable() function then ! :)

Comment: OK @GuedesBF ! Good to know it ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggeset the `DT` package?

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---
```{r setup}
DT::datatable(mtcars, class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(pageLength = nrow(mtcars)))
```
````

[image]

With just 1 line of Rmarkdown code, we get, what I think is a VERY close representation of the `View()` output you would get. the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package is very easy to use and will make your HTML reports look very professional, with options for number of rows per page, downloadable tables, search ability, and pivottable abilities

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel Jachetta ! That's exactly what I was looking for ! :)